# VBA: Finding a value, copying row, pasting row somewhere else, Finding the next value

Tags: excel, vba

So here is what I want to do in VBA:
Find the value in E10, copy the row it is in, paste the row somewhere else (doesn't matter as long as I can find it) then finding the next row with the value E10 and doing the same thing, etc, until I reach the end of the spreadsheet

I'm really new to VBA and macros in general, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010014111.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you'll find that asking questions without explaining "what have you tried" tends to be frowned upon in these parts.

I suggest that you take a look at this somewhat similar question that I answered just earlier today:

[Copy & Paste row of data in Excel 2003 to different sheet by Email search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517213/copy-paste-row-of-data-in-excel-2003-to-different-sheet-by-email-search)

The principal differences between that one and your need are:

- Instead of an InputBox, you'll use the value in E10 to run the .Find method; and
- You need to create a loop. You still run the .Find method as shown in my example but you do it in a loop until you've looped through every instance of the value in E10 in the sheet. (Get the address of the first range that you find, and keep running the .Find method until you get back to that address.) Look up the While statement and the For statement in VBA help for examples on how to create a loop.

To get the value of an individual cell one way is just to create a reference to the cell range, then query the .Value property. For example a fully qualified reference could be:

```
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E10").value
```

There are other syntaxes which will yield the same result, but you can learn about those in time. Recording your actions using the Macro Recorder is a good way to learn about properties and methods. The problem is that in yet another part of the Excel 2010 interface that I detest, Microsoft has decided to hide the thing. To get to the Macro editor, go to File -> Options -> Customise Ribbon and turn on the Developer tab.

Give all of that a try and if you get stuck with something specific, post again with the details.

Comment: I love how, in certain quarters here, even mentioning a particular topic is "badgering" or otherwise "unacceptable". I stand by what I said and the reason that I said it. It wasn't to berate the OP, and it wasn't to make myself big. It's because I've been around online forums and similar long enough to know how things actually work in the real world. If someone asks questions regularly but doesn't give some form of indication that an answer worked for them, people who CAN answer the questions may stop doing so. It has been thus since the days of Usenet, it will be thus to the end of time.

Comment: In addition to which I've seen enough comments along those lines to suggest that there may be a less than ideologically pure diversity of opinions on whether it's "bad enough" for the rate to be mentioned. Giving newer user a heads up on where they may encounter problems dealing with the wider populace may not be "good enough", but I think it still has certain advantages especially given the relatively arcane upvoting/downvoting/green ticking/flagging/only if you have enough rep structure here, which takes some getting used to. The OP may not have even previously realised what the tick meant.